# Fastlane error: The software asset has already been successfully delivered

Tags: azure-devops, testflight, fastlane

We are using fastlane in AzureDevOps pipelines to upload our .ipa file to TestFlight. This was working fine until recently, when some builds did not appear on TestFlight. I figured from logs, that the builds which are not in TF have there

> 2022-10-25T03:41:38.0866400Z [03:41:38]: The software asset has already been successfully delivered.

This line in the log is not present when the build is on TestFlight. Do you know how this can happen? We automatically increment the build number every time we run this, so we never have duplicate app versions.

The fastlane command is (I obfuscated some IDs):

> [command]/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/bin/fastlane pilot upload -u *** -i /Users/runner/work/r1/a/output/myapplication.ipa -q XXXXXXXXX -a com.myapplication.app --skip_submission true --skip_waiting_for_build_processing true -p 0123456899 -asc_provider XXXXXXXX

Comment: Hello, did you  managed to have it working? What if you increment the "build number" ?

Comment: I'm getting this issue too. updated both build and version number but didn't work.

Comment: I was able to upload to testflight by incrementing the build number only for the last version which already listed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As mentioned in [this](https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/issues/20811) or [this](https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/issues/20741) fastlane thread, you just need to add environment variable

> ITMSTRANSPORTER_FORCE_ITMS_PACKAGE_UPLOAD = 'true'

In my case, adding it is Variable in my Azure DevOps release pipeline.

Comment: As a reminder for myself, If you are using a bin/bash script use:
`export ITMSTRANSPORTER_FORCE_ITMS_PACKAGE_UPLOAD=true`

Comment: Could you please provide a bit more infomation as to where this environment variable was set in Azure DevOps? There's a fair few places and methods that variables can be set and I was hoping for a bit more infomation.

Comment: @Reisclef you add it just as a variable in release pipeline. Edit your release pipeline, select tab "Variables", select "Pipeline Variables" on the left and simply add new variable. Key is ITMSTRANSPORTER_FORCE_ITMS_PACKAGE_UPLOAD and value true.

Comment: Perfect, thanks very much @DavidGregor! I was going about this completely differently. Thanks for those steps, they helped! :)